# How to mix Socket.io and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, socket.io

I have developed a web app that requires Socket.io to push notifications to users. Given that, is it best to use Socket.io for all communication between the clients and the server or to use ordinary AJAX calls for all communication that doesn't require Socket?

Thanks!

Comment: socketIO's unique thing is instant notifications. usually, http interaction is more debuggable, more secure, more logged, and easier to impliment on the backend due to its req/res model (as opposed to just a bunch of events). In short, both work, but ajax has a lot more tools/benefits if you don't need out-of-the-blue data.

Comment: But given that I have to use Socket.io for some communication, should I be using it for all of them? Or is it better to have a mix?

Comment: i think you should use the best tool for the job. i like to use sockets for timing and some light message delivery, if it saves a trip or two. but for important things, i prefer to let the client know via websockets that it's time to grab something via ajax. why? because the ajax is better secured and logged and gives me a lot of flexibility in handling a response in a custom manner, without having yet another global socket listener...

Comment: @dandavis - How is the Ajax better secured?

Comment: @jfriend00: the ajax calls use the same login authentication that our pages already have. they can also be conditionally redirected after page load, whereas sockets get stuck on the "same url". in theory, there is nothing inherently safer to http, but for us, and i'd imagine most shops, http has a lot more momentum and existing tools that would be by-passed via sockets needing a lot more custom code. so for example, if i want to remove a user account, doing so via http provides a much better audit trail than our socket server software provides. you also "KNOW" ajax made it and back...

Comment: @dandavis - I agree with much of what you said, but if the webSocket has already been authenticated, then it would be a ton more efficient to use the already authenticated webSocket than to authenticate a new Ajax connection and it would be just as secure.  So, I think you may have a convenience argument because of the plethora of HTTP tools (which I agree with in my answer), but I don't see a security argument.  A websocket can be just as secure as an Ajax call.  In the end, they are both just socket connections initiated from the client and they both start out as HTTP requests.

Comment: i think we agree if you consider that i equate "HTTP tools" with security; even lowly router logs increase security because they assist prosecution of criminals, which in-turn deters attacks. on a level playing field, both transports are (sans exploits) just as technically secure. but, i think that the playing fields out there are by no means level, and that's why i "still" use ajax professionally.

Comment: @jfriend00: in fairness, instead of "better security" i probably should have said something like ajax has "better security options", or "easier security integration"... forgive my brevity.

Comment: @dandavis - yeah, I'd agree with that.  But, if one has already gone to the trouble of securing the webSocket connection, then it's there to be used.

Answer (score 3):

There is no right answer.  If you already have a live webSocket connection and you know you will have that, then is is perfectly acceptable to have the client send messages over that webSocket to request data.

Whether you use the webSocket for that or use an HTTP Ajax request is really more a matter of which seems easier to you in both client and server.

A webSocket request "should" be slightly more efficient because the socket is already open and connected (so you avoid the socket setup overhead of an HTTP call).  And, if you're running over https, then it has even more setup overhead. But, there exists a lot of useful infrastructure for processing HTTP requests on the server (sessions, templates, lots of middleware, debug tools, proxies, etc...) that might be easier to use for an AJAX call.  And, Ajax calls may also be useful as an API when a webSocket is not already open).

There are pros/cons both directions so it really depends upon the type of request, the tools used to fulfill the request and your own preference.